# Disable Tab in TabBar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, tabbar

I have a small problem which is hopefully nothing for you. :-)

I have a tabbar in mxml-Form. It looks like that:

```
<mx:TabBar id="tabBar_" itemClick="clickEvt(event);" selectedIndex="1" creationComplete="check()">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:Object label="Components" data="{ComponentTabOverview}"/>
        <mx:Object label="Products" data="{ProductTabOverview}"/>
    </mx:dataProvider>
</mx:TabBar>
```

Now I have the problem that I have to check after creating the tabbar, from which state the tabbar is created.
And if its created from an particular state, the first tab has to be disabled.

I did that as follows:

```
public function check():void {

        if(checkstate_){

           tabBar_.getChildAt(0).enabled= false;

        }   
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Can somebody help me out?

Thanks!!!!

Mike

Comment: Looks like there is no direct solution for this, you might have to extend the tab bar and the override the data provider property. Your dataprovider object would become like below.

<mx:Object label="Components" data="{ComponentTabOverview}" enabled="false"/>

Now you have to override updateDisplayList/commitProperties to enable or disble the child tab button. I do not have flex installed right now, or else i would have given the solution to you by code, but the above desc should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an undocumented (it's marked `@private` in the ASDOCs) property in the `NavBar` component called `enbaledField`. The `TabBar` component extends `NavBar` at some point in it's class hierarchy.

Here is the code from the Apache Flex github repo (included just so you can read the ASDOC comments):

```
/**
 *  @private
 *  Storage for the enabled property.
 */
private var _enabledField:String = "enabled";

[Bindable("enabledFieldChanged")]
[Inspectable(category="Data")]

/**
 *  Name of the the field in the <code>dataProvider</code> object
 *  to use as the enabled label.
 *  
 *  @default "enabled"
 *  
 *  @langversion 3.0
 *  @playerversion Flash 11.1
 *  @playerversion AIR 3.4
 *  @productversion Flex 4.10
 */
public function get enabledField():String
{
    return _enabledField;
}
```

So theoretically (I don't have Flex installed either), if the elements in your `dataProvider` have a property called `enabled` you can disable individual buttons in the `TabBar`.

Alternatively, if you'd like to use some other field in the dataProvider elements to indicate that the button should be enabled/disabled, you can set a new value on the `enableField` property.

The caveat seems to be that the ASDOC says this was first included in Flex 4.10. But I think that is odd since this is an older MX component.  However, it could be that this property was indeed added in Flex 4.10.

If it's true, that this is only in Flex 4.10, then you could copy the respective bits of code and implement it yourself as @zeus suggested. In particular make note of the private method `createNavChildren()` in the `NavBar` class where the magic happens:

```
//Check for enabled field and assign it to the individual button if it exists.
if (_enabledField != "" && item.hasOwnProperty(_enabledField) == true)
{
    navItem.enabled = Boolean(item[_enabledField]);
}
else
{
    navItem.enabled = enabled;
}
```

[Here is a link](https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/blob/develop/frameworks/projects/mx/src/mx/controls/NavBar.as) to `NavBar` class in the github repo that has all of the above code.

Comment: This was an enhancement as part of the Apache Flex 4.10 release. see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-14522

Comment: @JustinMclean thanks for explaining! I misread the ASDOC, `enableField` is not undocumented code after all... I guess the OP will have to either upgrade to Flex 4.10 or copy the implementation of this feature. Cheers!